# Getting subdirectories recursively but only up to a level

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

I stumbled upon a very simple problem today. I have a directory structure like this:

```
main_dir
    |_A
       |_X
       |_Y  
    |_B
       |_X
       |_Y 
    |_C

       |_X
         |_PP
         |_QQ 
       |_Y
         |_PP
```

I want to recursively get all the subdirectories upto the level where `X` and `Y` are present. I don't want to include `PP` and `QQ` in that list.

I tried this:

```
mai_dir = Path("main_dir")
subdirs = [x for x in iter(main_dir("**/*")) if x.is_dir()]
```

The problem with this approach is that it includes these results as well:

```
main_dir/A
main_dir/B
main_dir/C
main_dir/C/X/PP
main_dir/C/Y/QQ
```

I want to exclude these results. I know I can apply another `for` loop with `if-else` but I am wondering if there is a way to avoid a loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` matches all files and directories. If you want to match only some particular directories, say so explicitly.

```
mai_dir = pathlib.Path(".")
print(list(mai_dir.glob("**/[XY]/")))
```

If a single glob won't cut it, you can create two or more lists and merge them.

Comment: `main_dir.glob("**/*[XY]/")`, I think this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import os
path = r"c:\MyDownloads"
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    if root[len(path)+1:].count(os.sep)<2:
        print(os.path.join(root))
```

or this:

```
import pathlib

path = r"c:\MyDownloads"
mai_dir = pathlib.Path(path)
for i in list(mai_dir.glob("**/")):
    if len(i.parts) < len(mai_dir.parts) + 3:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Anything equivalent in `pathlib` module?

Comment: No worries. Thank you

Comment: I thought you wanted to get the structure from your main dir and only two level below. Sorry.